# How to get the correct SQL result in complex sql with 4 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, where-clause

We have a sql query where we use 3 inner joins and a massivly complex where-condition. We have the following 4 tables:
Table 1: Avis - it is a 1:n to table 2 (bound on Avis.Id=Item.AvisFk)
Table 2: Item - it is a 1:n to table 3 (bound on Item.Id=Routesection.ItemFk)
Table 3: Routesection - it is a n:1 to table 4 (bound on Routesection.TourFk=Tour.Id)
Table 4: Tour

Now we use a WHERE condition where we filter some dates, locations, and so on. Now we have the problem, that there are some special Item-Ids that we don't want to have. We get some wrong results. 
There exist Avis that have many Items. Now we want to filter ALL Avis that have at least one of the undesired Items. But from the Tour-Query.

I tried it with 
    `WHERE (SELECT Count(*) FROM Item WHERE OemFk=5003 AND AvisFK = Avis.Id) = 0` 
But we have to use some GROUP BY's and there we group all Avis to one Tour.Id so that we get a 'true' every time, because there are some Avis on this Tour that have the undesired Item and some don't...

Has someone an idea how I could approach the problem?

EDIT:
Ok, I try to give you a basic what I really mean. Lets say we have 2 data rows in Avis. Rows: ID; (only what is really needed)
`1;`
`2;`
Then lets say we have some items in Item. Rows: ID; AvisFk; OemFk;
`1; 1; 5001;`
`2; 1; 5002;`
`3; 2; 5003;`
`4; 2; 5004;`
Then the Routesection (a little bit more rows, I only put here some in for the reference of the example). Rows: ID; ItemFk; TourFk;
`1; 1; 1;`
`2; 1; 1;`
`3; 2; 1;`
`4; 2; 1;`
`5; 3; 2;`
`6; 3; 2;`
`7; 4; 3;`
`8; 4; 3;`
At last but not least the Tour. Rows: ID;
`1;`
`2;`
`3;`
Ok, now I want to query the Tour table. Result should be only Tour 1. The desired result would be to get the tours where the inner join on the other tables have no relation to the special condition. The condition is: If an item has the OemFk 5003, then ALL items that come from the same Avis (in this case 3 and 4) have to be filtered out. The SELECT references to nearly 40 columns and the WHERE includes 5 more conditions and EVERY column in the SELECT is also inside the GROUP BY, so I tried to only show the minimum needed and not the complete query.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Try to add a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) if possible.

Comment: Does this not just a require a 'having' clause?

Comment: Hard to help with a query when the query isn't posted. Just sayin'

Comment: use a WITH command to pre-filter your tables into 4 CTE expressions, then with the data you wanted, join the CTE 'tables' - is a suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Cato was right, sadly I couldn't mark it as the correct answer, because it was only a comment. 
I manged to get the correct results with a "WITH" statement. I first filtered the tables in a combined INNER JOIN on all 4 tables, selected the NOT desired results as a kind of "Black List" and used that with a LEFT JOIN to select from the Tour all results that were not in the WITH result.
It looks now to something like this:

```
WITH partresult AS
(SELECT TourFk
 FROM Routesection r
 INNER JOIN Item i ON r.ItemFk=i.ID
 INNER JOIN Avis a ON a.ID=i.AvisFk
 INNER JOIN Tour t ON r.TourFk=t.ID
 WHERE (put some strange selections here ;)
        AND i.OemFk=5003)
SELECT t.ID, etc.
FROM Tour t
INNER JOIN Routesection r ON t.ID=r.TourFk
INNER JOIN Item i ON i.ID=r.ItemFk
INNER JOIN Avis a ON a.ID=i.AvisFk
LEFT JOIN partresult p ON t.ID=p.TourFk
WHERE p.TourFK IS NULL
      AND (nearly the same selections as above, so the server is a little bit faster)
GROUP BY t.ID, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...there are some Avis on this Tour that have the undesired Item and
>   some don't...
>
> Has someone an idea how I could approach the problem?

Look into using WHERE EXISTS().

Comment: I already tried that, but its the same problem as above. When I put the WHERE clause in the EXISTS, than there is the problem with the GROUP BY. Because the clause could be something like `WHERE Avis.Id=x`, but the Id's are grouped, so I won't get the correct one or I get all and then the WHERE clause is always true even when I ask for !=x

Comment: You would need to show me a real example of your EXISTS() clause, relating to your sample data, for me to understand why it isn't working for you.   `Avis.Id=x` doesn't mean anything to me.  I bet you aren't correlating it to the outer query.